# Is it possible for android watch to connect a server (with IP and port) directly (without phone)?

Tags: android, sockets, client-server, wear-os, android-watch

I'm making client program for android watch (of android wear OS) using socket connection.

In my server & client program for general computer, I'm trying to change the client part to that for android watch. But, I cannot find a sample code related to socket connection for android watch (of android wear OS).

I learned that android watch usually connect google cloud server through phone, and it is possible to directly connect via WiFi without phone. (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer) Those are related to Wearable Data Layer API.

My questions are as follows. I'm not sure that android watch as client directly connects our server (with IP address and port number). If possible, could you give some sample codes for socket connection or URL for the codes? (I googled the related codes but I couldn't find them.)

I hope your many comments and welcome any comment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hardware you may or may not be able to connect directly (i.e. without relying on a phone) to your server.

For supported devices you can setup a network connection using the [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) as described in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/network-access) on Google's developer website.

Once you have established a network connection you should be able to connect to your server.